# Get the index of a row in a table from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, rows

I have a table with two columns and multiple  rows, the first column has names and the second one has buttons, how can I get the name next to the button when I click any button.

The names will be taken from a database and the buttons will be generated from code behind depending on the number of names I have in my database.

Let's say that I have this:

```
<asp:table runat="server" id="table1">
    <tr><td>Name1</td><td><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Name2</td><td><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Name3</td><td><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save"/></td></tr>
 </asp:table>
```

How can I know which name is next to the button, when I click any of them, I want to get the name so that I can save it in a database.

Comment: Please post a code snippet of atleast 10-20 lines of code :) That line of code isn't enough...

Comment: So you want the name of the button OR the name at the left side (first column) of the button?

Comment: I just want to know how to get the index of the clicked button which is inside  the table, I'm new to asp and c#.

Comment: I want the name next to the button or the index of it

Comment: Which control you used to listing  ? Table or gridview or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use for your designer code something similar to this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvUsers_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="detail_LB" runat="server" Text="Detail" CommandName="Detail_LB" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Notice the **OnRowCommand** and for the LinkButtons the **CommandName** and **CommandArgument**. The argument contains the row number, where you clicked the button.

In your code behind:

```
    protected async void gvUsers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Detail_LB")
        {
            //index contains the row number
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            //get text in the cell next to the button
            string text = gvUsers.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
        }
    }
```

If hope this helps you to understand how to work with tables.